# In MIPS, what are HI and LO

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

I'm reading about division in MIPS and I've found that div

> Divides $s by $t and stores the
> quotient in $LO and the remainder in
> $HI

https://web.archive.org/web/20201111203150/http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html

And Wikipedia says

> HI and LO are used to access the multiplier/divider results, accessed by the mfhi (move from high) and mflo commands.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture

Are HI and LO registers?  What number registers are they?

Comment: And if they are not registers, are they spots in memory?

Comment: No, they are registers, it is just that they can't be encoded in the 5 bit register fields in MIPS instructions. Those "numbered" registers are accessed by using the appropriate number on the register field. The HI/LO registers have special instructions that allow them to be transfered to a "numbered" register.

Comment: Related: [Difference between rem and mfhi in MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53171112).  They exist to avoid write-back conflicts with normal 1-cycle latency instructions, and to simplify hazard detection for the general-purpose integer registers.

Comment: note that they were removed in [MIPS release 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64_Release_6)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

These are *special registers* used to store the result of multiplication and division. They are separate from the `$0 .. $31` general purpose registers, not directly addressable. Their contents are accessed with special instructions `mfhi` and `mflo` (Move From HI/LO).

They are present in the Multiply Unit and are 32-bits each. More info [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181017221013/http://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-14/ass14_3.html).  As a pair, they hold the 64-bit full result of a 32x32-bit integer `mult`.

---

Raymond Chen's blog article [The MIPS R4000, part 3: Multiplication, division, and the temperamental HI and LO registers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180404-00/?p=98435) has some very good info about early MIPS's non-intuitive behaviours, including `mtlo` / `mtlo` invalidating the previous `hi` / `lo` (respectively).

The incomplete integer instruction-set reference (linked in the question) for early MIPS also has some details, http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html, or see MIPS's official PDF manuals, or PDFs of manuals for classic MIPS CPUs.

Comment: Also, the less-often used mthi and mtlo access them.

Comment: and `mfhi` and `mflo` stand for "move from" HI/LO (source: http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html)

Answer (score 12):

HI and LO are not numbered registers, IIRC.  They are only used to store the results of operations that would not fit in a single register (e.g. multiplying two 32-bit integers could result in a 64 bit integer, so the overflow goes in HI).

edit: according to [this class description](https://web.archive.org/web/20160930072531/https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/classes/473/notes/mips.html), they are indeed special registers, so they are not numbered, and only accessible using special commands.

Comment: The link seems to be behind a paywall.

Comment: The link is dead (403)

Comment: The high half of a full-multiply shouldn't be considered "overflow".  It's just the high half (and a full-multiply like 32b * 32b => 64b can't overflow).  If the high-half is non-zero, a 32b * 32b => 32b multiply would have overflowed...

Answer (score 2):

What LO does is that for multiplication, it stores the least significant bits, and HI stores the rest of the bits, but mainly, we just focus on the LO part for multiplication. In division, we focus on both. LO in division is where the quotient should be stored at and HI is the remainder.