# Difference between rem and mfhi in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

Is there any difference between this:

```
rem $s0, $t0, $t1
```

and this:

```
div $t0, $t1
mfhi $s0
```

I know that the first one works but I'm not sure about the second. Is it the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

older MIPS didn't have `rem`, only a `div` that put the results into special registers, to avoid microarchitectural problems with write-back to the register file from a high latency instruction in a simple pipeline.

It's not the `mfhi` that's computing the remainder, it's `div` (producing its result in the `lo=quotient` and `hi=remainder` special registers).  `mfhi` is just "Move from HI"; it copies from that special register to a general-purpose register.

The names come from the `mult` instruction (which like `div` has higher latency than `add` or any other integer ALU instruction supported by original MIPS I), which produces a double-width result in LO and HI.  ([Getting result from mult in mips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597994/getting-result-from-mult-in-mips) and 
[In MIPS, what is HI and LO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320196/in-mips-what-is-hi-and-lo)).

If the destinations of `mult` and `div` were general-purpose registers, then in the cycle the results were ready, there might also be an `add` or `lw` or whatever other result that the pipeline needed to write to the register file in the same cycle.  And those instructions produce 2 word results each.  Using special LO/HI registers avoids write-back conflicts from both causes.

Also remember that MIPS stands for Minimally Interlocked Pipeline Stages, so a major design goal for early MIPS was to not have hardware even check for data dependencies, and leave that up to software to not try to read a result before it was ready.  Making `mult` / `mfhi` / `mflo` special also helps with that, because there isn't a dependency through a normal GP register.

---

But more modern MIPS CPUs have a much larger transistor budget, and can support instructions like `mul` and `rem` that put their results in GP registers even though they have higher latency than normal ALU instructions.

I'm not sure when they were added to the ISA; whether that was in the era of high-performance out-of-order execution MIPS CPUs like r10000.